# Kafka Streams - Tasks/Partitions/Processor relationship

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am using the low-level API processor.  I have a topic with 6 partitions.  In the class that implements the `Processor<K,V>`, I have defined some class variables (non-static).  I understand that there will be 6 tasks.  When we start the stream app, I see that there are 6 object being instantiated of the class that implements the `Processor<K,V>`.  Can we relate these object instances to tasks?  During re-balance, I assume that the partitions can switch over from one to another task either on separate thread OR to another instance.  If so, would a new object be instantiated of the class that implements the `Processor<K,V>` for the partition that got re-assigned on a different thread or instance and the close method be invoked on the existing object corresponding to that partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a task is moved from one thread to another, the task will be closed and a new task including a new Processor object will be created.

Thus, all local member variables are ephemeral by design.

If you need any state that is kept between rebalances, you need to attach a store to the `Processor`.

Comment: Hi Matthias, thank you, the above cleared my confusion on the state of the processor object between rebalances.

Comment: Sorry, missed to ask this, would the close method be invoked during the rebalance meaning when the task gets closed?  If so, is it possible to call the context.forward() method for one last time from the close method?

Comment: Processor#close() is called each time a rebalance is happens. If the task in re-assigned, Processor#init() is called after rebalance finished and before processing resumes. Calling `forward()` is not allowed because downstream nodes might have been closed already -- there is no guarantee about the order in which `close()` is called for all processors. Cf the JavaDoc of close: `Close this processor and clean up any resources. Be aware that {@link #close()} is called after an internal cleanup. Thus, it is not possible to write anything to Kafka as underlying clients are already closed.`